# How to include comments under posts in a clean build template?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, blogs

I am new to wordpress theme development and currently building building my first one from scratch, I have hit an issue with adding comments with blog posts.

I have the loop the that returns each post:

```
<div class="eachPost">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<article <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php
the_title();?></a></h2>

<p class="entry-meta">by <?php the_author_meta('first_name'); ?>
<?php the_author_meta('last_name'); ?> in <?php the_category(", ")
?></p>
<p class='right'><a class='comments-count' href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%')
?></a></p>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</article>
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I believe that I need to call the function:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

but adding this to the code has no effect.

I have comments.php and comment-template.php in the same folder as the file and believe that I need to include these in the page as follows

```
<?php get_template_part('comments.php'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('comments_template.php'); ?>
```

Using in config

```
<?php define('WP_DEBUG', true);?>
<?php define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);?>
<?php define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);?>
```

Create no error in logs or info.

In a clean build template how do you include comments under posts?

Comment: Your first code block gave me cancer...

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski why is this marked down? Is it not better to show what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

The comments.php needs to be inside the Template root folder, please take a look at the Wordpress Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

If you want to have it somewhere else, here's the Wordpress recommendation:

> The path to the file used for an alternative comments template should
>   be relative to the current theme root directory, and include any
>   subfolders. So if the custom comments template is in a folder inside
>   the theme, it may look like this when called:

```
<?php comments_template( '/custom-templates/alternative-comments.php' ); ?>
```

You see no errors because there's no mistake there. The system is calling a function that should load a file that if it doesn't exist, no error is thrown.